# Show current day's value at the top followed by other days

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

There is a list of rows that I can get from a table on the basis of restaurant ID. For e.g.

```
SELECT id, start_time, end_time, day FROM restaurant_timings WHERE restaurant_id = 2
```

Output does look like

```
1 6:00am 7:00pm Sunday
2 6:00am 5:00pm Monday
3 6:00am 4:00pm Tuesday
4 6:00am 7:00pm Wednesday
5 6:00am 9:00pm Thursday
6 6:00am 6:00pm Friday
7 6:00am 7:00pm Saturday
```

These results are returned in an array @timings. Now, on the front-end I want show these results according to the current day. With that said, if today is **Wednesday** then I need to show **Wednesday** at the top and **followed by all other days**. I am using a loop to do this. Here is the loop code:

```
<% @timings.each do |val| %>
<tr>
   <td><%= val['day_name'] %></td>
   <td>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class='input-group date datetimepicker1' id='datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control editabletext" name="openingtime[]" value="<%= if val['opening_time'].present? then val['opening_time'].strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p") end %>" readonly/>
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar icon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Should/Can I modify the SQL query to not to make front-end code complex? Any ideas on how can I do this?

Comment: So you want to change the way the array is ordered, right?

Comment: Yes @Bustikiller. So, we have the current day's entries at the top and followed by other days. It will automatically be changed daily.

Comment: Something to think about: http://rextester.com/UTX11602

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s easier to modify the backend code in this particular case:

```
@timings = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute %|
  SELECT id, start_time, end_time, day
  FROM restaurant_timings
  WHERE restaurant_id = 2|

until Date.today.public_send("#{@timings.first.day.downcase}?") do
  @timings.rotate!
end
```

or, even better:

```
@timings.rotate!(Date.parse(@timings.first.day).wday - Date.today.wday)
```

Comment: Getting this: NoMethodError (undefined method `day' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Restauranttiming:0x000000042b8f78>):

Comment: @SatishSaini, fixed

Comment: @llya: order("day < Date.today.wday, day") I am trying to do this but it doesn't work. Can you correct me here?

Comment: Even the properly passed today `order("day < ?, day", Date.today.wday)` won’t work because there are _strings_ in the database, and `wday` is an integer. BTW, what’s wrong with rotating 7 items? Why do you insist on doing this in the database?